# cvCaptureFromCAM not working in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.3

Do`cvCaptureFromCAM` not woking in iPhone or iPad. It can not open the device camera. I have applied

```
CvCapture* capture =  cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
CvCapture* capture =  cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
CvCapture* capture =  cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );
```

but every time it returns `null`.
Does cvCaptureFromCAM load live streaming in ios device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/opencv-on-ios/source/browse/trunk/samples/CameraFaceDetectionExample/CameraFaceDetectionExample/CameraFaceDetectionExampleViewController.m?spec=svn9&r=9

Comment: here is use mCVCam = cvCaptureFromCAM(1); i also used it before but it does not open my iPad camera. It always returns null.

Comment: hello iPatel did you work on the sample code? I have tried with this code but here still unable to open the camera. Any further suggestion. Thanks

Comment: sory..i have no idea of this code ... i got this code ..and give u for help perpose